# Linux; sort data and print only highest value of one column

Tags: linux, sorting

With linux, I try to sort my data based on the 1st and 2nd column and print only the line with the highest value in the 3th column. My data looks like

```
A 1 75.0
A 1 99.0
A 2 68.0
B 1 66.0
B 1 50.0
B 2 75.0
B 2 80.0
```

The "keys" are in column 1 and 2, and than I want to print only the line that have the highest value in the 3th column, when the data of column 1 and 2 is equal, like this

```
A 1 99.0
A 2 68.0
B 1 66.0
B 2 80.0
```

I tried to do it with sort, `sort -k1,1 -k2,2` , but how can I change the command that it only prints the line with the highest value in column 3?

Comment: Why do you sort it by a different key at all if you only care about the one row with the highest value in a column? Just sort on that column and pipe to `tail -n 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just a single `Awk` solution for this, instead of clubbing multiple option flags in `sort`

```
awk 'unique[$1FS$2]<$3{unique[$1FS$2]=$3; next}END{for (i in unique) print i,unique[i]}' file
```

The idea is that we create hash-table with key as first two columns, table name is `unique` and key is `$1FS$2` and then we add the largest value to the table per unique key and once all the lies are printed we print the hash table in the `END` clause.